# update table based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to update a column in table based on some condition.

here is the table -

```
DGTID |   SKAcc     |      Linkedaccount        |   DGTStatus 
 1      8002180831     8102651144,8005370302          C
 2      8005370302           8002170111               I
 3      8002012348                                    I
```

So, for a particular DGT ID, if status = 'C' and if Linkedaccount is present in any other SKAcc, then DGTStatus for that SKAcc should also be C.

Lets say, DGTId = 1, it has DGTStatus as 'C' and it has a linkedaccount = '8005370302' which is the SKAcc for DGTID='2' . So, its DGTStatus should also be 'C'

Now, I believe the main part here is to extract linked account as there can be multiple comma seperated linked account.

This is what I wrote to extract linked account -

```
select  replace(''''+LinkedAccount+'''',',',''',''')  from IDCOPES..T_CDI_WHT_DGT where ISNULL(LinkedAccount,'')<>''
```

This gives me '8102651144','8005370302'.

and then, I wrote -

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from IDCOPES..T_CDI_WHT_DGT where DGTID=1 and DGTSTATUS='C')
    UPDATE IDCOPES..T_CDI_WHT_DGT
    SET DGTSTATUS='C' 
    Where SKACC in (select  replace(''''+LinkedAccount+'''',',',''',''')  from IDCOPES..T_CDI_WHT_DGT where ISNULL(LinkedAccount,'')<>'' and DGTID=1)
```

But, this doesnt work.
However, when I write

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from IDCOPES..T_CDI_WHT_DGT where DGTID=1 and DGTSTATUS='C')
    UPDATE IDCOPES..T_CDI_WHT_DGT
    SET DGTSTATUS='C' 
    Where SKACC in ('8102651144','8005370302')
```

It works. I can't understand why it won't work when both code are same.

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store lists of numbers as strings!

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Thought of doing that but i can't fix structure of table. That can't be changed

Comment: Why not, @geek? Numbers and strings have very different sort orders (did you know that `'9'` is greater than `'8999999999999999999'`?) and if you're going to be passing ranges, your queries are going to perform awfully with the required implicit/explicit casting.

Comment: correcting the structure might seem lots more work then finding a workaround for your current problem. But not fixing it will make that you will need lots and lots more workarounds in the future. Do yourself a favor and fix the structure now

Comment: @Larnu Oh. So, when I use that replace statement, it returns me a number?
The thing is, datatype of linkedaccount is varchar and i am not authorised to change it. I will have to work a different way out to extract linked account.

Comment: @GuidoG i am really sorry but can't change the structure. It is used in other projects as well. I need to figure out another way :(

Comment: No, `REPLACE` will return a `varchar`, @geek. My point is, if you had a clause like `WHERE AccountNumber BETWEEN 10000000 AND 20000000 ` you'd either need to cast/convert `AccountNumber` to an `int` (which you can't) or pass the 2 string literals as strings, which would would mean you get wrong results.

Comment: @Larnu oh. So, if replace returns a varchar, it should work, right? But i am not able to update

Comment: If you have to query delimited data, you'll want to look at `STRING_SPLIT` or this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows. but the **real** answer is fix the data model.

Comment: @Larnu Oh, i got it. So, if I am able to fix the data model, I should change the datatype from varchar to?

Comment: @Larnu I can't use STRING_SPLIT since  I am using Sql server 2014

Comment: Yes, if you fix the delimited data and have a database with a proper many to one relationship, then your new table will have a column of the data type `(big)int`, and you can simply use a "proper" `WHERE` like `WHERE LinkedAccount = 1234567890`.

Comment: Why I linked to an existing answer too @geek; or you could look up `delimitedsplit8k_LEAD`.

Comment: @Larnu I cant use a where clause like this, WHERE LinkedAccount = 1234567890, because I am calling this statement in another stored procedure. So, i need to extract multiple seperated accounts and I cant directly use a value in where clause

Comment: Yes, @geek, that's because of the (bad) design choice, and why you need to use a string splitter; like those I mentioned above (or have the design fixed).

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from IDCOPES..T_CDI_WHT_DGT where DGTID=1 and DGTSTATUS='C')
UPDATE IDCOPES..T_CDI_WHT_DGT
SET DGTSTATUS='C' 
 Where SKACC in (
SELECT 
LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Certs
FROM
(
SELECT  *,CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(LinkedAccount,',','</RowData> 
<RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM   IDCOPES..T_CDI_WHT_DGT
where LinkedAccount like '%,%'
)t
 CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n))
```

Comment: I can't use string_split since I am using 2014 version

Comment: @Geek, i changed my query. please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the update logic as below-

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(
    DGTID INT,
    SKAcc VARCHAR(MAX),
    Linkedaccount VARCHAR(MAX),
    DGTStatus VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @TempTable (DGTID,SKAcc,Linkedaccount,DGTStatus)
VALUES( 1,'8002180831','8102651144,8005370302','C' ),
( 2,'8005370302','8002170111','I'),
( 3,'8002012348',NULL,'I' )

SELECT * FROM @TempTable

UPDATE A
SET A.DGTStatus = 'C'
FROM @TempTable A
INNER JOIN @TempTable B ON B.Linkedaccount LIKE '%'+CAST(A.SKAcc AS VARCHAR(MAX))+'%'
AND  B.DGTStatus = 'C'

SELECT * FROM @TempTable
```